# $P(|X| \geq \lambda a) \geq (1-\lambda)^2a^2$

Tags: probability

I am given that $E(X^2) = 1$ and $E(|X|) \geq a > 0$, as well as $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Somehow, I'm now expected to prove that $P(|X| \geq \lambda a) \geq (1-\lambda)^2a^2$.

Considering the context, I'm expecting to be using Markov's inequality, Chebyshev's inequality, Hölder's inequality, or Jensen's inequality. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, each of them only give upper bounds, whereas I'm supposed to find a lower bound. I've of course already found that $P(|X| \geq \lambda a) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda^2a^2}$, but I again don't see how this is useful in anyway.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is there perhaps a typo in your inequality and the lower bound should actually read $(1-\lambda)^2 a^2$ rather than $(1-\lambda^2) a^2$?

Comment: Yes, correct, my apologies. I will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your assumptions, the Paley-Zygmund inequality (see (*) below) gives
  $$P(|X| \geq \lambda a) \geq (1-\lambda)^2 a^2.
$$
This can be sharpened a bit, as noted there, but the form you stated is wrong.
Suppose Y takes values $1/2$ and $3/2$ with probability $1/2$ each. Write 
$a^2:=1/E(Y^2)=4/5$ and let $X=aY$. For $\lambda=0.51$ we have
$$P(|X| \geq \lambda a)= P(Y \ge \lambda)=1/2 < (1-\lambda^2) a^2.
$$

(*) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality